# Is it still possible to play Overwatch or are we forced to use Overwatch 2?

Tags: overwatch, overwatch-2

Just wondering is it still possible to play Overwatch or are we forced to use Overwatch 2?  I just wanted to play the PvP mode.

Comment: What do you mean by "FPS mode"? Isn't every mode in Overwatch/2 all FPS?

Comment: Note I updated the [tag:overwatch] tag earlier today specifying that the game has been shut down for Overwatch 2.

Comment: I'm assuming you mean PvP mode but if that's wrong feel free to rollback

Answer (score 25, accepted):

Overwatch 1 is no longer playable. [Source](https://mp1st.com/news/overwatch-servers-down-permanently-in-prep-for-ow2-this-october-3)

Overwatch 2 is free-to-play and available to play as of today.  Owners of Overwatch 1 [will get a free DLC](https://dotesports.com/overwatch/news/overwatch-owners-will-get-overwatch-2-founders-pack-dlc-for-free).